# How to fix the issue in running my NativeScript app in android?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

I typed : tns run android in the terminal and the default emulator API23 popsout but it did not install my app instead I got an error as stated below.Unlike when i run it in IOS simulator which runs without any error.

> Cannot run your app in the native emulator. Increase the timeout of
>   the operation with the --timeout option or try to restart your adb
>   server with 'adb kill-server' command. Alternatively, run the Android
>   Virtual Device manager and increase the allocated RAM for the virtual
>   device.

Any help would be appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: first start the emulator manually then tun the tns command...

Comment: I just solved my issue. I just downloaded the latest emulator in my Android Virtual Device Manager. and  when I run my app again, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes! I just solved my issue by downloading emulator in my Android
>   Virtual Device Manager. And I run my Nativescript application in
>   android. It worked. If you have the same problem I stated above,
>   please check in your Android Virtual Device Manager if you haven't
>   downloaded emulator first. Make sure you download the latest emulator.